# sublime package error on startup

Tags: sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

I am getting error saying :

```
Package Control

Error executing: /usr/bin/git symbolic-ref -q HEAD

xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun

VCS-based packages can be ignored with the "ignore_vcs_packages" setting
```

every time i sart my sublime, How do I use ignore_vcs_packages ? as mentioned in last line of error message.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Select `Sublime Text > Preferences > Package Settings > Package Control > Settings - User` to open you the `Package Control` settings.

Inside that file, add the setting:

```json
"ignore_vcs_packages": true
```

The configuration file is a JSON file, so make sure that all settings are separated with commas.

This setting can be set to either an array of package names if you want to ignore only certain packages, or the boolean value `true` to ignore all packages. Since your problem is that you don't have git installed, you probably want to go with the boolean version.

You can fix the underlying error by installing the XCode command line tools, which will net you the git command. See for example [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/254380/macos-sierra-invalid-active-developer-path).